# Cannot Edit .cs file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am facing a problem in editing .cs files in my project, I recently installed visual studio 2013 on a fresh operating system Windows 8.1 x64. 
It is not letting me edit the Project files i created here, 
**I have read articles and Stackoverflow threads** but every one here is referring to Resharper tools that i have not installed on my machine. so besides resharper tools cache clearing method, please suggest other solutions. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? What error messages or other unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: No error message. it simply disabled editing in .cs files in my projects

Comment: all your screenshot is showing is that `Form1.cs` isn't read only, and that in Visual Studio `Form1.cs` is open in a different tab;  The file that is open in the current tab, `Program.cs`, is empty.

Comment: Have you tried to open it with normal text editor? such as: sublimetext / notepad.

Comment: @Claies yes, this how it disabled editing, I cannot edit any file here

Comment: @W92 yes, I can edit it using notepad, but not in visual studio

Comment: what you are describing still doesn't make any sense.  what happens when you try to edit the files?  there aren't any locks here or any indications that you wouldn't be able to edit the file, if it was on the current tab....

Comment: @Claies, Yes it does not make any sens to me too. I had opened the Program.cs file but I was not able to edit it, it is not editable

Comment: as in, you literally can't type in the window?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to type and cannot even see the default code that is generated

Comment: In the solution explorer, right click on one of your .cs files and pick `open with...`.  Which editor is set as the default?

Comment: in editor like notepad, i can view and edit the .cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved. Since, it was the fresh installation, I forgot to register the product before starting on it, After I had registered the product and it allowed me to edit files!

Comment: I encountered the same phenomenon, I assume that it is a bug, that does not show any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio.
Open the folder that contains your .cs file, select the file and open it's properties. Remove any checked "read-only" or similar property.

Reopen Visual Studio and edit your file.